# Is there a way to find which function in typescript compiler correspond to which action in vscode

Tags: typescript

I want to know what happen in the typescript compiler when I select an item in the completion list, but I don't know what function it calls. Like:

```
x.
```

when I typing the `.`, a completion list shows up, this action will trigger `getCompletionsAtPosition` in `/service/completions.ts`. I used to do it by searching similar name in typescript compiler, but it doesn't work all the time, is there an accurate way to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code uses the TypeScript server to power JavaScript and TypeScript features. You can look at VS Code's TS Server trace to see which actions are being invoked:

1. In VS Code, set `"typescript.tsserver.trace": "messages"`
2. Open the output panel and go to the `TypeScript` section.

This lists the server requests that are sent:

```
[Trace  - 2:11:30 PM] Sending request: updateOpen (4957). Response expected: no. Current queue length: 0
[Trace  - 2:11:30 PM] Sending request: getApplicableRefactors (4958). Response expected: yes. Current queue length: 0
[Trace  - 2:11:30 PM] Response received: getApplicableRefactors (4958). Request took 105 ms. Success: true 
[Trace  - 2:11:30 PM] Sending request: geterr (4959). Response expected: yes. Current queue length: 1
[Trace  - 2:11:30 PM] Sending request: navtree (4960). Response expected: yes. Current queue length: 0
```

`getApplicableRefactors`, `geterr`, and `navtree` are the request names. Look for these in the TS codebase